# Trialforce: No unpackage code may be distributed in trials

Tags: managed-package, metadata, trialforce

We are going to use Trialforce as a way to deliver our managed package in already installed and pre-configured form to potential clients.

As we know, there are some artifacts which can not be packaged and some configurations can not be applied as a part of package post install script. So I consider Trialforce templates as a way to sort of bypass all these SF-related managed package limitations.

The way I see it, we install managed package in template org, deploy some additional unpackagable artficats on top of it along with some customization (e.g. assigning flexi pages to profiles, creating custom metadata record etc.)

But looking through SF Security Review requirements, I've come accross the following statement:

**`No unpackage code or other components may be distributed in trials.`**

My question here is - does this rule include unpackagable metadata components as well? Is it considered to be a bad practice to deploy additional metadata components after package installation? How then could I automate manual configuration steps required to be done by a client? What is then the notion of Trialforce template - is it just about loading some data on top of our package and that's it?

Thanks in advance for your help